# How to convert int into a char array?

Tags: c++

If I want to compile the following code:

```
int x = 8;
int y = 17;
char final[2];

final[0] = (char) x;
final[1] = (char) y%10;

cout << final[0] << final[1] << endl;
```

It shows nothing. I don't know why? So how can I successfully convert it?

Comment: "It shows nothing" What are you expecting to show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(char)8` is not `'8'`, but the ASCII value 8 (the backspace character). To display the character 8 you can add it to `'0'`:

```
int x = 8;
int y = 17;
char final[2];

final[0] = '0' + x;
final[1] = '0' + (y%10);

cout << final[0] << final[1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your program you are printing char 8, and char 7.
They are not printable. In fact they are BELL and Backspace characters respectively.
Just run you program and redirect it to a file.
Then do an hexdump, you will see what is printed.
./a.out > /tmp/b
hd /tmp/b
00000000  08 07 0a                                          |...|
00000003

Comment: Whilst this explains the OP's problems, it doesn't explain how to fix it: _"So how can I successfully convert it?"_

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand is that in C++, chars are *numbers*, just like ints, only in a smaller range. When you cast the integer 8 to char, C++ thinks you want a char holding the *number* 8. If we look at our [handy ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), we can see that 8 is BS (backspace) and 7 is BEL (which sometimes rings a bell when you print it to a terminal). Neither of those are printable, which is why you aren't seeing anything.

If you just want to print the `87` to standard output, then this code will do that:

```
cout << x << (y%10) << endl;
```

If you really need to convert it chars first, then fear not, it can still be done. I'm not much of a C++ person, but this is the way to do it in C:

```
char final[2];
snprintf(final, sizeof final, "%d%d", x, y % 10);
```

(See [snprintf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf))

This code treats the 2-char array as a string, and writes the two numbers you specified to it using a `printf` format string. Strings in C normally end with a NUL byte, and if you extended the array to three chars, the final char would be set to NUL. But because we told `snprintf` how long the string is, it won't write more chars than it can.

This should also work in C++.

Comment: While not an answer for C++, the format string should be `"%c%c"` to print 2 characters

Comment: @Kevin: That's an easy mistake to make, but `"%d%d"` is correct, since we want to print two integers. They just happen to be one character long. `"%c%c"` would interpret them as character codes, and have the same problem as the OP's code.

Comment: Ah yes my fault. I thought you were printing the characters not the integers